# Trouble linking C program with assembly file in Visual Studio 2019; Invalid or Corrupt File Cannot Read

Tags: c, visual-studio, x86, masm, masm32

I need to run masm assembly code in a C program for a project, as a test I'm trying to make a simple function that adds two numbers together and use it in a C program. I created a new project in *Visual Studio for C++*, renamed the file to .c, pasted the assembly code in notepad (saved as add.asm) and compiled using `ml /c add.asm`; I linked the .obj file it generated to the Visual Studio project (right clicked the solution explorer, add existing...) and made sure the path to it appeared on the linker config. However when I try to build the solution it gives me the same error:

> Severity   Code   Description   Project   File   Line   Suppression State
> Error   LNK1107   invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x92   projectName   C:\Users\myName\source\repos\projectName\assembly snippets\add.obj   1

I've recompiled the assembly code multiple times and yet it still shows as corrupted.
Anyone have an idea on what it could be?
I've been at it for hours and its hard to find anything related online

The assembly code for said function is as follows

```
.386
.model flat, C
.stack 4096

.data
    ; Define any data variables here (if needed)

.code

PUBLIC _add_numbers

_add_numbers PROC
    push ebp               ; Save the previous base pointer
    mov ebp, esp           ; Set the new base pointer

    mov eax, [ebp+8]       ; Get the first parameter
    mov edx, [ebp+12]      ; Get the second parameter
    add eax, edx           ; Add the two numbers

    pop ebp                ; Restore the previous base pointer
    ret                    ; Return from the function
_add_numbers ENDP

END
```

The code for the C program is

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern int add_numbers(int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
    int result = add_numbers(3, 5);
    printf("Result: %d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to check if you are using the correct platform (x86) in VS. I often get similar errors (actually, not exactly the same), until I figure out that "x64" is selected.

Comment: thats the dropbox next to the debug dropbox and the debugger run arrow right? It is in x86

Comment: Yes, that's I was talking about. But if it's already set to x86, your problem is due to something else. Sorry. By the way, what happens if you try the command "dumpbin /disasm add.obj"? Does it disassemble the obj correctly?

Comment: My guess is that you aren't using the version of ML that can be installed with Visual Studio (Maybe you have ML installed with MASM32 or something like that?). I'll guess your version of ML might be a version 6.xx (or earlier) where the default is OMF 8088 objects. You can check your version of `ML` doing `ML /?` . If you are using an older version you may wish to try `ml /c /coff add.asm` to generate an 80386 COFF object. Alternatively you could install (if it isn't already) the version of ML available with Visual Studio.

Comment: Another useful bit of info is that you can create a C/C++ project in Visual Studio and then add the MASM target by right mouse clicking the project, select `build dependencies` from the menu then `build customizations`. Put a check by the `masm(.targets .props)`. click `Ok`. Now add a file called `add.asm` to your project. You can do that by right mouse clicking `source files` in the project, select `New item` then enter the name of your asm file `add.asm`. Clock `ok` . Remove anyhting you added to your linker command line and remove the `add.obj` you added to the project.

Comment: If you do that then every `.asm` file will automatically be assembled with ML.EXE for x86 projects or ML64.EXE for 64-bit projects to an object file and that object file will be automatically linked into the final executable.